# Run js function n times

Tags: javascript, numbers, counter

I have a number counter script.

```js
var $findme = $('#numbers');
var exec = false;

function Scrolled() {
  $findme.each(function() {
    var $section = $(this),
      findmeOffset = $section.offset(),
      findmeTop = findmeOffset.top,
      findmeBottom = $section.height() + findmeTop,
      scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop(),
      visibleBottom = window.innerHeight,
      prevVisible = $section.prop('_visible');

    if ((findmeTop > scrollTop + visibleBottom) ||
      findmeBottom < scrollTop) {
      visible = false;
    } else visible = true;

    if (!prevVisible && visible) {
      if (!exec) {
        $('.fig-number').each(function() {
          $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
            Counter: $(this).text()
          }, {
            duration: 2000,
            step: function(now) {
              $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
              exec = true;
            }
          });
        });
      }
    }
    $section.prop('_visible', visible);
  });

}


function Setup() {
  var $top = $('#top'),
    $bottom = $('#bottom');

  $top.height(500);
  $bottom.height(500);

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    Scrolled();
  });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  Setup();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hww-whyus-item-num" id="numbers"> <span>0</span> <span class="fig-number">9</span> </div>
```

I need to add function to repeat count 'n' times: e.g. count starts from 00 to 05 and repeat once again from 00 to 05 three times. Or it can be the random numbers but the most important is the final number - I need to have ability to create animation with changing numbers but I need to control the final number and total time of the animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use promises like this

```
// number of runs
var times = 3;
// number of items
var items = 6;
 
// makes a promise which will resolve when all items are made
let makeItem = () => {
  return new Promise( (done) => {
    for(var i = 0; i < items; i++){
       console.log('Item #0' + i);
    }
    done();
  });
}
// run asynchronoulsy and wait until makeItem is done to execute next iteration
let run = async () => {
  for(var i = 0; i < times; i++){
       console.log('Run #' + (i + 1));
      await makeItem();
    }
}

run();
```

**Edit:** Sorry your code uses jquery so I updated my answer using jquery as well:

```
// number of runs
var times = 3;
// number of items
var items = 6;

container = $("#container");

function makeItem(it, el) {
  for(var x = 0; x < it; x++)
  {
    el.append("<li>item #0"+x+"</li>");
  }
}

async function run(times){
    let result;
  for(var i = 0; i < times; i++){
    container.append("<h2>Run #"+(i + 1)+"</h2>");
    try{
      result = await makeItem(items, container);
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
  }
}

run(times);
```